# A random integer from 65 to 69 ('A' to 'E') and store it to AL register

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

Hi I'm new at Assembly language, and I tried to make a random integer from 65 to 69 ('A' to 'E') and store it to AL register. This is my code.

```
;------------------------------------------------------------
GetChFromABCDE PROC USES eax
;
; Generates a char randomly from 'A','B','C','D','E'
; Receives: Nothing
; Returns: The char ASCII code in AL
;------------------------------------------------------------

mov eax, 5          ; get random 0 to 4
call RandomRange    ;
mov eax, 41h        ; make range 65 to 69
mov value1, eax
mov al, BYTE PTR value1

GetChFromABCDE ENDP

END main
```

Whenever I try to figure out what a problem is in this code, a debugger says 'Source not available' and 'Source information is missing from the debug information for this module'. I guess the problem part is this.

```
mov value1, eax
mov al, BYTE PTR value1
```

My professor says try to use registers instead of memories as possible as I can, but this time I have no idea to fix this problem..

Comment: On your comment "Whenever I try to trace the problem, ...", you realise you haven't actually *told* us what the problem is, yes? The best questions include the smallest code sample exhibiting the problem (yes), the expected behaviour (yes), and the *actual* behaviour (no). That would go a long way toward helping us help you.

Comment: What debugger are you using, and how are you building the code?  (That's really a separate question from debugging this, which you should solve e.g. by setting your debugger to use disassembly instead of looking for source.)  Trying to debug asm without using a debugger to single-step is a waste of your time (and everyone else's), so sort that problem out first.

Comment: @paxdiable Maybe I should have said 'Whenever I try to figure out what a problem is in this code,' because the real problem is that I don't know which part is wrong to my code. But I will try to follow your instruction next time.

Comment: @PeterCordes Wow this is my first post and I'm learning so much things from you guys. I'm using VS 2019 and I simply click 'Start Debugging' or press F5. And your saying is so true! I will sort the problem first.

Comment: Post your answer as an answer, not an edit to the question.  And don't bother keeping around the buggy version without `ret`.  SO posts have an edit history so we don't have to leave useless stuff to distract future readers.

Comment: @PeterCordes I followed your instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

I realized I forgot to put `ret` in the GetChFromABCDE PROC!
Here is the final answer.

```
GetChFromABCDE PROC 

    mov eax, 5        ; get random 0 to 4 
    call RandomRange  ; 
    add eax, 41h      ; make range 65 to 69
    ret

GetChFromABCDE ENDP
```

Comment: I notice you also removed the `USES eax` from the declaration.  IIRC, that would have made MASM save/restore EAX around this function (magically adding instructions before yours and before the ret), so restoring the original EAX would replace your return value.  I guess that might be useful for people who understand asm already, but MASM's magical features are just confusing for learning asm.

Answer (score 2):

```
mov eax, 41h        ; make range 65 to 69
```

Ah, ..., no it doesn't :-)

It *sets* `eax` to be `0x41/A`. I think what you *meant* to do is:

```
add eax, 41h        ; make range 65 to 69
```

---

Additionally, I'm not sure why you even *have* that code for storing the random value into `value1` then retrieving it (where you think the problem may lie):

```
mov eax, 41h        ; make range 65 to 69 (should be add)

; I mean this code below:
mov value1, eax
mov al, BYTE PTR value1
```

The `al` register *already* has the random value in it by virtue of it being the least significant octet of `eax`. Since you never use `value1` anywhere else, this seems superfluous.

---

You may also want to examine what should be done after a subroutine is finished. Something *called* it, so it should ***return*** to that caller. In other words, a `ret` is needed.

---

And, as a final note, I believe the `uses` clause of `proc` automatically creates push/pop instructions to save and restore the values in those registers. So you *don't* want a `uses` listing one of the registers you want to return a value in, since the `pop` before `ret` will overwrite that value.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right.
but still not fixed.

Comment: @Sammie, I was pretty sure it wouldn't *fix* the whole, I just noticed that glaring error and responded to  "Any kinds of comments are welcome". Although that sounds like a *bad* idea to me, you may get all sorts of abusive responses :-)

Comment: I agree. It would be better to delete the last comment.

Comment: That was exactly what my professor said. Below is my previous code.
```
GetChFromABCDE PROC

 mov eax, 5   ; get random 0 to 4
 call RandomRange ;
 add eax, 41h  ; make range 65 to 69

GetChFromABCDE ENDP
```
He said I missed an important part at the end of GetChFromABCDE, and I thought the important part is to store the `eax` value to `al`. Now I'm confusing what the important part is..

Comment: @Sammie, ah, now I see (you may want to mention things like that next time). If you can't figure it out from my just-added, not-very-cryptic final paragraph, let me know and I'll make it more explicit. If that's possible :-)

Comment: I missed very basic one. I edited the final answer.